# insert TIMESTAMPDIFF() into exising column in same database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to calculate the total time it takes to get a ticket done upon completion. 
I have a `tickets` table in my database that records information for each ticket with the primary key being the `ticket_id`.

When my form is submitted, the mysql query in my php code sets the completion_time in the database for that ticket id as `now():

```
UPDATE tickets 
SET completion_time = NOW() 
WHERE ticket_id = :ticket_id;
```

the next query i want to execute is calculating the total_time and storing it in an existing column in the `tickets` table with respect to the `ticket_id`. The `creation_time` and `completion_time` are `TIMESTAMP` datatypes, and the `total_time` is an `INT` datatype since I want to return the time in minutes as an integer value.

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE tickets 
SET total_time = TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,@completion_time,@creation_time) 
WHERE ticket_id = :ticket_id;
```

I am not sure if I have to execute the two code snippets in separate queries; as of now, they belong to the same variable `$sql` and are executed in the same query in the php code.

Comment: The field which's value is defined by (and may be calculated from) the values of another fields of the same record always, must NOT present in a table (as static at least - but it can be a generated column freely).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the timestamp difference in the same query as inserting the completion time:

```
UPDATE tickets SET completion_time = NOW(), total_time = TIMESTAMPDIFF(NOW(), creation_time) WHERE ticket_id = :ticket_id
```